# How to correctly declare data variable with type?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am trying to use typescript in my Vue.js project, and have met trouble with setting type of variable. I declare variable word in data like this

```
        const word: firebase.firestore.DocumentReference | null = null;
        const state: CreatingGroupSteps = 0;

        return {
            isFormValid: false,
            groupNameRules,
            state,
            word,
            groupName: '',
            show: false,
        };
```

but in method when value of DocumentReference assign to variable word i got error from `tslinter` http://prntscr.com/o4bi42
looks like variable word is of type `null` instead of `DocumentReference | null`
How can I fix it?
Thanks

Comment: can you try to remove ' | null' part? Probably DocumentReference iis nullable anyways. Typescript is trying to match DocumentReference to DocumentReference AND null types. There it fails. You can also add a nullcheck in your method.

Comment: It's not safe to assume that the type is nullable. But your code example here shows `const word` and your screenshot shows `this.word`. Those two are definitely not the same variable, so maybe `this.word` is declared as `DocumentReference` only, not as `DocumentReference | null`.

Comment: i should set initial value to ```word``` and it should be ```null```, so if i remove ```| null``` part tslint warn me that i cant assing null to type DocumentReference

Comment: Recommend using vue-class-components (https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/blob/master/README.md) and vue-property-decorator if you are using typescript. You use the vue-cli to generate projects with this built in. The main difficulty is that there's very little official documentation.